# Django database autherization Central server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, django

HI I am new in Django and I have an project about it. It has mysql database and I want to change the structure of the the database and make some permissions and authterization in the structure of the this database using central server  but I don't know where I should begin to study 
As I  mean I need some documents to learn the authterization in django 
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please do your homework. Here are some links for helping you do your homework:

- [User authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/)
- [Tango with Django: User authentication](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/login.html)
- Django: [Getting started](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/)